# Javascript ReferenceError: Value is not defined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

My following function encountered the following error when triggered in `Dynamics` form.

> ReferenceError: heightStart is not defined

```
function Start(type) {
    debugger;
    alert("Start | type: " + type);
    if (type == "heightStart") {
        var height = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ccc_heightincmstart").getValue();
        if (height != null && height != "") {
            GetChildInfo(height, type);
        }
        else {
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ccc_heightpercentilestart").setValue("");
        }
    }
}
```

May I know how can I fix this error?

`type` is a value passed in with Web Resource File Handler mapping.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass parameter with double quotes like “heightStart”

[image]

[Read more](https://nishantrana.me/2012/08/12/passing-parameters-to-javascript-web-resource-function-in-crm-2011/)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `Parameter` form is interpreting heightStart as a variable. Try wrapping it in quotes in the form; `"heightStart"`

Answer (score 0):

because you pass the executioncontext so the function should be

```
function(executioncontext, type) ....
```